# kindle users guide requires registration to read?

Tags: kindle, amazon, ebook-management, privacy, guide

A newly acquired Kindle running Firmware 5.8.9.0.1 has a Kindle Users Guide, Third Edition on the home screen.  Opening this just leads to "register your kindle."

How can I read the manual without registering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download user guides for all Kindle models from [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200317150).