# Kindle text editor?

Tags: kindle, editing, kindle-app, annotations, footnotes

Take note has a [nice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004JX4PCI) interface:

[image: keyboard]

But how do I install onto a seventh generation basic Kindle?  (Not fire, not paperwhite, [just](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/7700/9853) "regular".)

Would love a simple text editor outside of adding notes to a specific book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon no longer supports Active Content for *current* eInk Kindle models (the last supported model is the 6th generation Paperwhite). For more information see this [page](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/?&nodeId=200505220).

If you haven't updated your firmware to the latest version, you might be a able to [jailbreak](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=275881) it and to install a [homebrew editor app](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=191531).